node.js Buffer inconsistent UCS-2 encoding?
I'm trying to understand the implementation of the UCS-2 encoding in the node.js Buffer implementation.
In UCS-2, each character is represented by a 16-bit code in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF.
When I try to encode a character that lies outside of the range, for example U+1F60E:
Buffer.alloc(4, "", "ucs2")

I get this buffer:
<Buffer 3d d8 0e de>

I was expecting some kind of encoding error instead.
Those bytes aren't even the UTF-8 encoding, which would be <Buffer f0 9f 98 08>
Does anyone have an idea how node.js handles these out of range cases?
The node version is 18.19.0.
Thanks!

Does this answer your question? What is a "surrogate pair" in Java?

Note: Each UTF-16 character can be seen as one or two UCS-2 characters (no translation needed). javaScript use such old convention (UTF-16 was not yet invented at that time, and compatibility is important). But if you want to be modern (like various JavaScript description, just interpret UCS-2 as "Unicode Code Unit" (not code points), which it is the same as UCS-2 (but just requiring correct use of pair of surrogates). (And if you look JavaScript documentation, you may find duplicate functions using UCS-2 or UTF-16 character interpretation
